# What is the best practice to implement verify() method in HostnameVerifier?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, httpclient, x509certificate

I am implementing custom hostname verifier as follow's:

```
HostnameVerifier hv=new HostnameVerifier() {
        
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession sslSession) {
            try{
                if(flag.equalsIgnoreCase("testing")){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
             
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs= (X509Certificate[]) sslSession.getPeerCertificates();
                    for(int i=0; i< certs.length; i++){
                        
                        String sIssuedName = certs[i].getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
                        System.out.println("Verifying Portal Host Name Verifier. urlHostName:" + urlHostName + " and Issuer Subject: " + sIssuedName);
                        return verify(urlHostName, sIssuedName);

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception while verifying Certificate.");
            }
            return false;

        }
   };
```

The `verify(urlHostName, sIssuedName)` will basically be getting the CN from the certificate and doing some string matching similar to what is mentioned in this [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1).

I am setting my custome HostnameVerifer as follows:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLContext(sslContext)
            .setSSLHostnameVerifier(hv)                  
            .build();
```

I am trying to understand how Hostname verification needs to be carried out, any standard protocol that needs to be followed, or any best practices prescribed?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set a break point in the method, start the code, connect a debugger, wait until the breakpoint is hit, look at the call stack. This should show from where the method is called.

Comment: Hostname verification [use of certificate common names has been deprecated for over two decades](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1): "If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST be used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used. **Although the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is deprecated and Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead**."  Just about everything stopped using common name about five years ago now.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks, that helped, i had completely missed checking it, could see the call from SSLConnectionSocketFactory verifyHostname() method.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes I did read about it, this was a temporary implementation just to test out my connection to the server over SSL. I am going through SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier(), can that be used instead, or is there any best practice to implement HostnameVerifier ?